# how to draw this with gadfly in julia

Tags: julia, gadfly, julia-plots

I have got this dataset so far:

```
julia>import Downloads 
julia>using DLMReader, VegaLite, InMemoryDatasets 
julia>data=Downloads.download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akshdfyehd/salary/main/ds_salaries.csv") 
julia>ds=filereader(data,emptycolname=true) 
julia>new=filter(ds,:employment_type,by= ==("FT")) 
julia>select!(new,:job_title,:salary_in_usd,:work_year)
588×4 Dataset
 Row │ job_title                   work_year  experience_level  salary_in_usd
     │ identity                    identity   identity          identity
     │ String?                     Int64?     String?           Int64?
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Data Scientist                   2020  MI                        79833
   2 │ Machine Learning Scientist       2020  SE                       260000
   3 │ Big Data Engineer                2020  SE                       109024
   4 │ Product Data Analyst             2020  MI                        20000
   5 │ Machine Learning Engineer        2020  SE                       150000
   6 │ Data Analyst                     2020  EN                        72000
   7 │ Lead Data Scientist              2020  SE                       190000
   8 │ Data Scientist                   2020  MI                        35735
   9 │ Business Data Analyst            2020  MI                       135000
  10 │ Lead Data Engineer               2020  SE                       125000
  11 │ Data Scientist                   2020  EN                        51321
   ⋮  │             ⋮                   ⋮             ⋮                ⋮
```

I want to have two graphs, 1. first one with x axis be salary, color in experience level and y axis will be job title
2. second one is y axis be job title but they will be grouped by different work year, x axis be salary, color in experience level.The outcome should be sth like this:

[image]

for the first pic I have tried with this code

```
julia>palette = ["brown", "blue", "tan", "green"]
julia>plot(new, y=:job_title, x=:salary_in_usd, color=:experience_level,
    Geom.subplot_grid(Geom.bar(position=:stack, orientation=:horizontal),
        Guide.ylabel(orientation=:vertical) ),
    Scale.color_discrete_manual(palette...),
    Guide.colorkey(title="experience_level\ntype"))
```

but error raised saying no method match this. Does anyone know where I got this wrong? Many thanks!